# Cannot "pip install cryptography" in Docker Alpine Linux 3.3 with OpenSSL 1.0.2g and Python 2.7

Tags: python, linux, openssl, dockerfile, alpine-linux

**Solved** Wow, these guys are fast... It's basically this https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2750 It turned out that a security update for openssl was released (DROWN Attack) and that update contained an unexpected function signature change which caused the incompatibility, so this was just bad luck for me.

---

I need to use `pip install cryptography` in a Docker container running Alpine Linux. Actually, it's another module, `service_identity`, but the problem resides in the `cryptography` module, which is a dependency.

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk --update add build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev python-dev py-pip
RUN pip install cryptography
```

which fails with the following error

```
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
building '_openssl' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:726:6: error: conflicting types for 'BIO_new_mem_buf'
 BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *, int);
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:65:0,
                 from build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:434:
/usr/include/openssl/bio.h:692:6: note: previous declaration of 'BIO_new_mem_buf' was here
 BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(const void *buf, int len);
      ^
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

openssl 1.0.2g was released on 2016-03-01 (yesterday) and the alpine package already got updated to that version. Can it be related to this?

How can I resolve this issue? Maybe some environment variables which I can set?

**Update** I've been checking the GitHub Repo for openssl, and in fact `BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(void *buf, int len)` of `openssl/bio.h` got changed to `BIO *BIO_new_mem_buf(const void *buf, int len)` during the 1.0.2f to 1.0.2g transition (search for "BIO_new_mem_buf" in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/compare/OpenSSL_1_0_2f...OpenSSL_1_0_2g). I don't know where this `openssl/asn1.h` is coming from, which is importing an outdated version of `openssl/bio.h`, as it does not look like the one in the openssl repo. Any ideas?

Ok, I see some are already working on this:
https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2750

Comment: I had the same issue today installing cryptography 1.2.2, an upgrade to 1.2.3 solved it.

Answer (score 79):

For those who are still experiencing problems installing `cryptography==2.1.4` in **Alpine 3.7** like this:

```
writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
building '_openssl' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DNDEBUG -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:493:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

### Solution

Install these dependencies in the Alpine container:

```sh
$ apk add --no-cache libressl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev
```

To install these dependencies using a *Dockerfile*:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        libressl-dev \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir cryptography==2.1.4 && \
    apk del \
        libressl-dev \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev
```

### Reference

Installation instructions for `cryptography` on Alpine can be found here:

- https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux
- A version from the time of writing [is available on github](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/1340c00/docs/installation.rst#building-cryptography-on-linux)

Here is the relevant portion:

> ### Building cryptography on Linux
>
> *[skipping over the part for non-Alpine Linux]* …
>
> ```sh
> $ pip install cryptography
> ```
>
> If you are on Alpine or just want to compile it yourself then
>   `cryptography` requires a compiler, headers for Python (if you're not
>   using `pypy`), and headers for the OpenSSL and `libffi` libraries
>   available on your system.
>
> #### Alpine
>
> Replace `python3-dev` with `python-dev` if you're using Python 2.
>
> ```sh
> $ sudo apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev
> ```
>
> If you get an error with `openssl-dev` you may have to use `libressl-dev`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please elaborate on the code in the answer in case the link dies.

Comment: please elobrate your answer

Comment: The Question got solved back then by the developers of the `cryptography` module, which was out of sync with the `OpenSSL` library. The approach you are mentioning here replaces `OpenSSL` with `LibreSSL`. It provides a workaround, not a solution. Are all these libraries like `tini` and so on really required? Thanks for offering an alternative approach (I'm assuming that it works, won't try it out, though).

Comment: While rearranging your code for proper formatting, I noticed that you are actually not installing the module `cryptography`

Comment: @DanielF  Btw, I included tini and other libraries in example not in the actual solution. I am removing it if its too deviating....

Comment: JFYI, the docker command referenced above is missing `gcc` which is required for this to work.

Comment: For me adding `libressl-dev libffi-dev` solved the problem with `python:3.7-alpine`

Comment: `libressl-dev` saved me

Comment: Alpine 3.10 required `cryptography==3.3.2`

Comment: `libressl-dev` does not seem to work for all settings. With an outdated postgreSQL alpine image I get `ERROR: Service 'xyz' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add libressl-dev' returned a non-zero code: 2`.

Answer (score 14):

If it fails because of Rust version, then following is recommended in cryptography's docs:

```
The Rust available by default in Alpine < 3.12 is older than the 
minimum supported version. See the Rust installation instructions
 for information about installing a newer Rust.
```

```sh
$ sudo apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo
```

in my case,  python3.8-alpine,  adding `cargo` resolved.

Comment: "cargo" installs "Rust" (tested). Strangely, installing Poetry and having had at least a similar error at the point when Poetry tried to install "cryptography", the error of Poetry stayed the same also with the installed "cargo", still saying that it needs "Rust". I had to install "cryptography" on its own to get the installation done, like the accepted answer does. Having an older Python version, I also had to add a chosen version, see [Failed to install cryptography package with Poetry on Python 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68985895/11154841). After that, I could install Poetry.

Comment: I was having this issue without docker on Ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.6. I just had to use `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh` and add `$HOME/.cargo/bin` to my path to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before install:

`RUN apk -U upgrade`

`RUN apk add --no-cache libffi-dev openssl-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use build-base:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade --virtual .build-deps build-base
```

Details here: https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/build-base/APKBUILD?h=3.3-stable

Answer (score -1):

Check if you are building for the right architecture !!

x86-64 or amd64 architecture runs similar softwares and the other category is
aarch64 or arm architecture chips like Apple Silicon M1 or your mobile phone cpu

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30160203)